# combine two different queries into one

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following query:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT id, title
    FROM      
    ((SELECT 
        DISTINCT offers.id AS id, offers.title AS title

    FROM offers

    INNER JOIN categories
    ON offers.category=categories.title

    WHERE categories.title="Fashion clothes"

    GROUP BY offers.id
    ORDER BY offers.id)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT 
        DISTINCT offers.id AS id, offers.title AS title

    FROM offers

    INNER JOIN cities
    ON offers.city=cities.title

    WHERE cities.title="Australia"

    GROUP BY offers.id
    ORDER BY offers.id)) as subquery
```

I would like to fetch from the table offers the rows that have `category=Fashion` clothes and `city=Australia` but when I use Union it returns all the rows .
I don't know how to make it work. If anyone can help i would appreciate it.

Comment: I am not sure that you need `union` for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a union for this. Just join all the tables and have both conditions in you where clause:

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT offers.id AS id, offers.title AS title

FROM offers
INNER JOIN categories
ON offers.category=categories.title
INNER JOIN cities
ON offers.city=cities.title

WHERE categories.title="Fashion clothes" AND cities.title="Australia"
ORDER BY offers.id
```

As noted by RubahMalam you don't even need the joins as you are joining the tables by title, so the query can be simplified to:

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT offers.id AS id, offers.title AS title

FROM offers

WHERE offers.category="Fashion clothes" AND offers.city="Australia"
ORDER BY offers.id
```

However, it would probably be best to have separate unique id's in all your tables and use those to join them in your queries, but that's another story.

Answer (score 1):

You just need :

```
SELECT id,title
FROM offers
WHERE category = "Fashion clothes" OR city = "Australia"
GROUP BY id,title
ORDER BY offers.id
```

You don't even need `INNER JOIN` for this. And as patrickh003 said, you don't even need `GROUP BY` if id is unique column.

Comment: I agree. but you might not even need the group by (assuming that id is unique).

Comment: @patrickh003 Yes, but OP use group by in the question. So I guess that id isn't unique column.

Comment: I think your answer should be the right one. It's the most productive query. I can't think of why you would join in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you want both, then you can use aggregation and a *having* clause:

```
SELECT o.id, o.title
FROM offers o
WHERE o.category = 'Fashion clothes' AND o.city = 'Australia'
GROUP BY o.id, o.title
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
ORDER BY o.id;
```

If you can have duplicates in the `offers` table, then you need `COUNT(DISTINCT o.category)` in the `HAVING` clause instead of `COUNT(*)`.